# PdfMetamorphosis - rtf to pdf image alignment issues

Tags: c#, pdf, rtf

Is anyone on SO familiar with the PdfMetamorphosis library?
One of the functions it supports is the ability to convert an rtf into a pdf.
This functionality works great but I am having an issue with the alignment of images.

If my rtf has 2 embedded images side by side, after the convert the images are no longer aligned but rather one underneath the other.

The code I am using is as follows

```
        PdfMetamorphosis pdf = newPdfMetamorphosis();
        pdf.Serial = "xxxxxxx";
        pdf.PageStyle.PageOrientation.Portrait();
        pdf.PageStyle.PageSize.A4();
        string pfile = @"c:\temp\outFile" + DateTime.Now.ToFileTime() + ".pdf";
        pdf.RtfToPdfConvertFile(@"c:\temp\inFile.rtf", pfile);
        Process.Start(pfile);
```

It doesn't seem like I am doing anything specifically wrong.
The developer of the product hasn't been able to assist me, I am just hoping someone here on SO has has some experience with this library

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question just in case someone comes to this post.
The sad truth is that there is no solution to the problem as it stems from a limitation in pdfMetamorphosis to handle word docs created in office 2003. This limitation isn't mentioned anywhere on the website.

Developer has delayed us with fixes and as to this date hasn't fixed anything yet.

(No refunds on the cards either)